# word not in vocabulary after training gensim word2vec model, why?

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

So I want to use word-embeddings in order to get some handy dandy cosine similarity values. After creating the model and checking for similarity of the word "not" (which is in the data I give the model) it tells me that the word is not in the vocabulary.

Why can't it find the similarity for the word 'not'?

the description data looks as follows:
[['not', 'only', 'do', 'angles', 'make', 'joints', 'stronger', 'they', 'also', 'provide', 'more', 'consistent', 'straight', 'corners', 'simpson', 'strongtie', 'offers', 'a', 'wide', 'variety', 'of', 'angles', 'in', 'various', 'sizes', 'and', 'thicknesses', 'to', 'handle', 'lightduty', 'jobs', 'or', 'projects', 'where', 'a', 'structural', 'connection', 'is', 'needed', 'some', 'can', 'be', 'bent', 'skewed', 'to', 'match', 'the', 'project', 'for', 'outdoor', 'projects', 'or', 'those', 'where', 'moisture', 'is', 'present', 'use', 'our', 'zmax', 'zinccoated', 'connectors', 'which', 'provide', 'extra', 'resistance', 'against', 'corrosion', 'look', 'for', 'a', 'z', 'at', 'the', 'end', 'of', 'the', 'model', 'numberversatile', 'connector', 'for', 'various', 'connections', 'and', 'home', 'repair', 'projectsstronger', 'than', 'angled', 'nailing', 'or', 'screw', 'fastening', 'alonehelp', 'ensure', 'joints', 'are', 'consistently', 'straight', 'and', 'strongdimensions', 'in', 'x', 'in', 'x', 'inmade', 'from', 'gauge', 'steelgalvanized', 'for', 'extra', 'corrosion', 'resistanceinstall', 'with', 'd', 'common', 'nails', 'or', 'x', 'in', 'strongdrive', 'sd', 'screws']]

Note that I've already tried to give the data as separate sentences instead of separate words.

```
def word_vec_sim_sum(row):
    description = row.product_description.split()
    description_embedding = gensim.models.Word2Vec([description], size=150,
        window=10,
        min_count=2,
        workers=10,
        iter=10)       
    print(description_embedding.wv.most_similar(positive="not"))
```

Comment: Maybe because you removed stop words before passing the sentence tokenized to your model. Maybe because it was not trained for enough time to capture the embeddings of the word.

If neither nor, you have to handle the missing words, how? Assign -1 to the score because if the word is not there you can not compare it to another word as you do not have a vector representing its embeddings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to lower `min_count`.

From the [documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec): *min_count (int, optional) – Ignores all words with total frequency lower than this.* In the data you have provided `"not"` appears once, so it is ignored. By setting `min_count` to 1 it works.

```
import gensim as gensim

data = [['not', 'only', 'do', 'angles', 'make', 'joints', 'stronger', 'they', 'also', 'provide', 'more', 'consistent',
         'straight', 'corners', 'simpson', 'strongtie', 'offers', 'a', 'wide', 'variety', 'of', 'angles', 'in',
         'various', 'sizes', 'and', 'thicknesses', 'to', 'handle', 'lightduty', 'jobs', 'or', 'projects', 'where', 'a',
         'structural', 'connection', 'is', 'needed', 'some', 'can', 'be', 'bent', 'skewed', 'to', 'match', 'the',
         'project', 'for', 'outdoor', 'projects', 'or', 'those', 'where', 'moisture', 'is', 'present', 'use', 'our',
         'zmax', 'zinccoated', 'connectors', 'which', 'provide', 'extra', 'resistance', 'against', 'corrosion', 'look',
         'for', 'a', 'z', 'at', 'the', 'end', 'of', 'the', 'model', 'numberversatile', 'connector', 'for', 'various',
         'connections', 'and', 'home', 'repair', 'projectsstronger', 'than', 'angled', 'nailing', 'or', 'screw',
         'fastening', 'alonehelp', 'ensure', 'joints', 'are', 'consistently', 'straight', 'and', 'strongdimensions',
         'in', 'x', 'in', 'x', 'inmade', 'from', 'gauge', 'steelgalvanized', 'for', 'extra', 'corrosion',
         'resistanceinstall', 'with', 'd', 'common', 'nails', 'or', 'x', 'in', 'strongdrive', 'sd', 'screws']]


def word_vec_sim_sum(row):
    description = row
    description_embedding = gensim.models.Word2Vec([description], size=150,
                                                   window=10,
                                                   min_count=1,
                                                   workers=10,
                                                   iter=10)
    print(description_embedding.wv.most_similar(positive="not"))


word_vec_sim_sum(data[0])
```

And the output:

```
[('do', 0.21456070244312286), ('our', 0.1713767945766449), ('can', 0.1561305820941925), ('repair', 0.14236785471439362), ('screw', 0.1322808712720871), ('offers', 0.13223429024219513), ('project', 0.11764446645975113), ('against', 0.08542445302009583), ('various', 0.08226475119590759), ('use', 0.08193354308605194)]
```